Use Server Action in Client Component in NextJS
I'm trying to make this component in NextJS which needs to fetch some data from the backend but also a button to make it hiddeable.
Screenshot of the component
It's my first time using React and NextJS and I'm having problems with client and server components as well as server actions.
To my understanding, I have to use server actions to fetch data (which are async functions), but then I can use them only in server components, because client components don't support async/await.
But also I need my component to be client because to be able to hide it with a button I'm using useState hook.
This is some of my code:
export default function Dashboard() {

  return (
    <div className={styles.dashboard}>
      
      <div className={styles.widgets}>
        <Suspense fallback={<>Loading Streak...</>}>
          <StreakCard/>
        </Suspense>
        <Suspense fallback={<>Loading Stats...</>}>
          <StatsCard/>
        </Suspense>
      </div>

      <LineSeparator vertical/>

      <div className={styles.collapse_button}>
        <button>
          <ChevronLeftIcon className={styles.icon}/>
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

The StreakCard and StatsCard sub-components are fetching the data using  server actions like so:
export default async function StatsCard() {
  const weight = await getWeigth()  // server action
  const fat = await getFat()  // server action

  return (
    // (Omitted for brevity, it just uses the above variables in the html)
  )
}

I've been trying several things and reading the documentation but I guess my problem is that I don't really get how I should aproach to this.
